# Unable to select an element via XPath in selenium Webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a script in selenium webdriver python. Where I am trying to click on search field, but its always showing exception of "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."

Here is script:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    class Exercise:
        def safari(self):
            class Exercise:
def safari(self):
    driver = webdriver.Safari()
    driver.maximize_window()
    url= "https://www.airbnb.com"
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    Title = driver.title
    driver.get(url)
    CurrentURL = driver.current_url
    print("Current URL is "+CurrentURL)
    SearchButton =driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='GeocompleteController-via-SearchBarV2-SearchBarV2']")
    SearchButton.click()

note= Exercise()
note.safari()
```

Please Tell me, where I am wrong?

Comment: Actually I was trying to do with class earlier, I have updated the code..please check now.

Comment: whole script was run, means browser got opened, site was executed,I have got current URL, but didn't get click.

Comment: @TaimoorPasha There are  2 input with the same id. The second one is what is displayed. Switch the xpath to - "//main[@id='site-content']//input[@id='GeocompleteController-via-SearchBarV2-SearchBarV2']"

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried with xpath you gave, but still didn't worked.

Comment: @Grasshopper Also tell me, that is there any way that I can check whether I am XPath which I have created is correct one or not.

Comment: @TaimoorPasha Are you looking for the input or the search button? The id is from the input but the variable is named search button. If using chrome right click on the element and select inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be two matching cases:

[image]

The one that matches the search bar is actually the second one. So you'd edit your XPath as follows:

```
SearchButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@id='GeocompleteController-via-SearchBarV2-SearchBarV2'])[2]")
```

Or simply:

```
SearchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='GeocompleteController-via-SearchBarV2-SearchBarV2'])[2]")
```

You can paste your XPath in Chrome's Inspector tool (as seen above) by loading the same website in Google Chrome and hitting F12 (or just right click anywhere and click "Inspect"). This gives you the matching elements. If you scroll to *2 of 2* it highlights the search bar. Therefore, we want the second result. XPath indices start at *1* unlike most languages (which usually have indices start at 0), so to get the second index, encapsulate the entire original XPath in parentheses and then add `[2]` next to it.

Comment: Actually I was trying to do with class earlier, I have updated the code..please check now

Comment: Updated my answer. @TaimoorPasha

Comment: Thanks Mangohero1, that was really really great, can you teach me how to make xpath.

Comment: Sure @TaimoorPasha I've included some explanation about that (too big to fit as a comment)

Comment: please send me your skype id or email address at taimoorpasha2009@gmail.com